# Java - Question about implementation of HashMap

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a java program where the user enters a title for an activity for example "Football game". I want to add this to a hash map so that i cant use it to find this title when they type 1 or both the keywords when searching for the activity. For example my key is '1' because this is the first activity. How do i make both words "Football game" associated with activity 1?  Could someone please show me how this is done?

Comment: it is your homework!
 NP ,what is your sample code?!

Answer (score -1):

```
    Map<String, List<String>> footballHashmap = new HashMap<int, String>();
    footballHashmap.put(1, "Football Game");
    String value = (String) footballHashmap.get(1);//Will return football game
```